# WSL docker suddenly got "Operation not permitted" after the latest update (Docker Engine v19.03.5)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm using WSL + Docker and it's been working perfectly fine right before I updated my docker desktop, but after the the update, it doesn't seem to work anymore, it always says:

> "Operation not permitted"

Comment: What does say `Operation not permitted`? And when? Is there a more detailed error message? What are you doing? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: so first I updated my docker desktop (because it always bugs me to update), so I got now a Docker Desktop v2.1.05, and when I tried running my `docker-compose up` it started throwing me an "Operation not permitted" error and I can't get my app running..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what happened but I somehow got it working, so what I did is I tried nuking my containers and volumes and then tried to rebuild it. And that fixed my problem! Hope this helps.

got the commands from here...
https://github.com/Radu-Raicea/Dockerized-Flask/wiki/%5BDocker%5D-Remove-all-Docker-volumes-to-delete-the-database